# UV Editing - Strange line apearing where two sections meet

Tags: uv, edit-mode

I am trying to make textures for my little plane using UV Editing, however when I paint them and put them on a plane I get these what look like empty spaces between the sections. I have tried to bleed the edges few pixels each side but I still get the same result as it can be seen from the images. If anybody has an idea how to fix this I would really appreciate it.

Kind regards.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe your islans need more margin? or your brush needs more bleeding?

Comment: Hi @moonboots you are absolutely right, thank you. Things we overlook but they are so obvious.